# Angular - initiate a response when data loads/changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Relative Angular newbie here, and I am wrestling with what would seem like something most applications need:

**Watching a model/data and doing something when that model is hydrated and/or has a state change.**

Use case would be, when a user logs in (user model gets initiated) a complimentary directive/controller sees the state change, and then requests out to the backend to get a list of this users corresponding data elements (ie Notifications, emails, friends, etc)

Ive parsed through StackOverflow and such, and it always appears that a shared service is the way to go, however I never find a definitive answer about how the directives are to watch the state change.  Some suggest a broadcast/watch while others say that is a bad pattern.

Our app currently does employ a shared UserService, which contains model representation of a User (data and simple methods is fullName())

This service also has a subscription hook that directives can subscribe to

```
onLogin: (fn) ->
    $rootScope.$on userService::login, fn
```

and the use is:

```
UserService.onLoad(myFunction)
```

When the UserService loads the User, it then broadcasts userService::login and all the listeners are run.  Hence everyone that shares the UserService can subscribe and respond to a User logging in.

This all works.  But I was thinking there must be a built in Angular way that the directives can just know about the state change and then do myFunction (ie make additional data calls)

Thoughts and feeling would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Basically you could expose a two-way binding for the directive to watch but that is not efficient. Broadcasting events is much more efficient and robust than watching a variable.

Comment: @MuliYulzary thanks for the response!   Your suggestion would use a $scope.$watch()  of some sort?  I was thinking about that as well, and outside of angular performance, what _seems_ nicer about that is that if something is destroyed, I would think the watch goes along with it.  However, as you said, it probably has to hog up much resources to keep watching variables all over the place ?

Comment: the watcher won't go away unless the `$scope` is destroyed or unless you destroy the watch instance with the returned value from $watch. Ex: `var stopWatch = $scope.$watch(...);` then somewhere `stopWatch();`